# Add a Two Line Comment to Table Before Saving with Numpy savetxt

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Here is the Python 3 code giving me the problem:

```
name_in_stk = name+'.out.abs.stk'
data_stk = np.loadtxt(name_in_stk, skiprows=0)
wavelength = []
ext_coef = []
ext_coeff = [row[1] for row in data_stk ]
wavelength = 1e7/np.array([row[0] for row in data_stk ])

DataOut = []
DataOut = np.column_stack((wavelength,ext_coeff))

np.savetxt(name+'.stk',DataOut, fmt=('%5.1f','%5.4e'))
```

The output is:

```
435.6 1.8225e+04
396.7 3.2189e+04
333.8 3.7765e+03
325.2 4.6922e+04
315.5 1.0923e+05
307.0 9.9065e+02
296.4 1.3264e+03
288.2 5.6207e+04
282.8 3.4048e+04
266.1 2.5265e+04
```

The question that I haven't been able to answer, althought I have searched, is :

How do I add a two line header to this table before saving it?

Comment: pROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: Problem solved!

Comment: Problem!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`np.savetxt` has the option to specify a header, not (as I expected) by specifying a list of column names corresponding to the columns that you want so save, but by specifying a string to be placed as the start of the file, which will be commented out with a `#`. There is no option to create two headers, but since `savetxt` wants a string as the header, that makes thing easier as you can split the header string into two lines with `\n`.

A minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random(10).reshape(5,2)*100
header = '{0:^5s} {1:^7s}\n{2:^5s} {3:^7s}'.format('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
np.savetxt('test', data, fmt=('%5.1f','%5.4e'), header=header)
```

Produces this:

```
#  a      b   
#  c      d   
 39.0 7.4369e+01
 87.2 8.7414e+01
 50.0 7.7876e+01
 23.9 8.2554e+01
 87.7 8.9955e+01
```

As a side note: you can get individual columns loaded with `np.loadtxt` with e.g. `ext_coeff = data_stk[:,1]`, and in line with that, could calculate `wavelength` with `wavelength = 1e7/data_stk[:,0]`. If you are dealing with large data sets, that could speed things up quite a bit as you get rid of the manual loops (`.. for row in ..`). For a file with a million lines, I get a speedup of about a factor 60.

Comment: Despite not being fully documented, `np.savetxt` supports "officially" multi-line headers. The "proof" is that is you specify the comments argument, this will be automatically prepended to *all* lines, not just the first one. You can check it here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1410-L1412